# T flip flop won't produce outputs

Tags: verilog, flip-flop

I have made some verilog code and a test bench to create a T flip flop but cannot get the outputs to change to anything other than x. I've tried doing o/p as reg in the module and the testbench and then assigning the tb reg to a wire but didn't work. Not sure where it's being hung up.

Below is the flip flop module:

```
module Tflipflop(input T, S, R, En, clk, output reg Q, output Qn);

assign Qn = ~Q;

always@(posedge clk | R | S) begin
    if(R == 1'b1)
        Q <= 1'b0;
    else if (S ==1'b1)
        Q <= 1'b1;
    else if (En==1'b1) begin
        case(T)
            1'b1: Q <= ~Q;
            1'b0: Q <= Q;
        default: Q <= Q;
        endcase
    end
    else
        Q <= Q; 
end
endmodule
```

Below is the testbench:

```
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module Tflipflop_tb();

reg T, S, R, En, clk;
wire Qn, Q;

Tflipflop TFF_1(.T(T), .S(S), .R(R), .En(En), .clk(clk), .Q(Q), .Qn(Qn));

initial begin
clk = 0; T = 1; S = 0; R = 0; En = 1; #5;
clk = 1;                              #5;
clk = 0;                              #5;
clk = 1;                              #5;
clk = 0;                              #5;
clk = 0;                              #5;
clk = 1;                              #5;
clk = 0;                      En = 0; #5;         
clk = 1;                              #5;
clk = 0;                              #5;
clk = 1;                              #5;
end

endmodule
```

a picture of the simulation in modelsim:

[image: t_flip_flop simulation]

Comment: there is no place in your testbench where you allow the reset `R` or set `S` to be high for a while. So, your `Q` is not initialized properly.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems inside your DUT and testbench code.

- DUT: Use the event `or` operator, not the bitwise Boolean operator. You don't want the code sensitive to a rising edge of the expression `(clk | R | S)`. See [this link](https://www.edaboard.com/showthread.php?388945-The-difference-between-operator-and-keyword-or&p=1673142&viewfull=1#post1673142) for an explanation.
- TB: You need to set `R` or `S` to 1 to get the flop out of an unknown state.

Answer (score 1):

It's because the initial value of `Q` in `Tflipflop` is `x` by default. Either give it a different initial value like this:

```
initial Q = 0;
```

Or use the `R` or `S` inputs to set it.